# How to add page curl animation in ePub Reader app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, epub

I am using [AePubReader](http://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader) for reader ePub files. How can i add page curl animation for changing page. Currently pages are change when i swipe from Left to Right & Right to Left.

I have tried many way to do this but no luck yet.

Any one a idea on it.

Comment: Doing Page curl animation has been explained and a sample code has been given [here](http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2010/02/apples-ibooks-dynamic-page-curl.html). Hope that might help you.

Comment: @ Ilanchezhian: This link is not working. Can you please share the working link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Gesture recognizers to a UIWebView. Have a look at [this link](http://justinimhoff.com/swipe-gesture-with-uiwebview/) and integrate it to your reader.

Comment: This link is not working. Can you please share the working link?